# Delete Previous Files in Directory, Create New Files and Download Newly Created Files With Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, settimeout

I am creating a simple node application. What I want to achieve:

My application will take link of a web page and some keywords as an input. Now I want to create new web pages depending upon those keywords entered. So if I enter good programmer, great problem solver, nodejs developer. It should create 3 new files good_programmer.php,great_problem_solver.php. nodejs_developer.php And then I want to download these files.

My suggested solution for this issue is as following:

```
    const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const zipadm = require("adm-zip");
const zip = new zipadm();
// initialize app
const app = express();
// to handle the forms
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// initialize port
const PORT = 8000;
// util functions
function deletePreviousFiles() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fs.readdir(__dirname, (err, files) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (const file of files) {
                if (file.includes(".php") || file.includes("sitemap.txt") || file.includes(".zip")) {
                    fs.unlink(path.join(__dirname, file), err => {
                        if (err) throw err;
                    });
                }
            }
            res();
        })
    })
}
function generateSitemapFile(webpage, words) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        let keywords = words.split(",");
        for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            let fileName = keywords[i].trim().replace(" ", "_");
            let newLink = `${webpage}${fileName}.php`;
            fs.appendFile(`sitemap.txt`, `${newLink}\n`, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        }
        res();
    })
}
function generatePHPFiles(data, words) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        const $ = data;
        $.html();
        let keywords = words.split(",");
        for (let i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
            let fileName = keywords[i].trim().replace(" ", "_");
            fs.writeFile(`${fileName}.php`, $.html(), (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
            })
        }
        res();
    })
}
function createZipFile() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fs.readdir(__dirname, (err, files) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            for (const file of files) {
                if (file.includes(".php") || file.includes("sitemap.txt")) {
                    zip.addFile(file);
                    data = zip.toBuffer();
                    zip.writeZip("NewPhpFiles.zip");
                }
            }
            res();
        })
    })
}
// controller
const startApplication = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const webPageLink = req.body.link;
        const seoKeywords = req.body.keywords;        
        // delete previous files on desk
        await deletePreviousFiles();
        console.log("Previous Files Deleted...");
        // generate sitemap.txt file
        await generateSitemapFile(webPageLink, seoKeywords);
        console.log("Sitemap Created...");
        // get web page response
        let response = await axios.get(webPageLink);
        const data = await cheerio.load(response.data);
        console.log("Data Loaded From Page...")
        // create new php files
        generatePHPFiles(data, seoKeywords);
        console.log("PHP Files Created...")
        // create a zip file
        createZipFile();
        console.log("ZIP Created...")     
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
const downloadFile = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            res.download("NewPhpFiles.zip");
        },1000)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
app.use(startApplication)
// initialize the route for application
app.post("/submit", downloadFile)
// start app
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`App is listening on port: ${PORT}...`));
```

So, I am deleting existing php files on disk, then creating new files and zipping them but it doesn't download new file. Seems it takes so much time to create new files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't fully understand how js works. Lets start with that. For example lets take deletePreviousFiles function. fs.readdir and fs.unlink has callbacks and you need to wait for those callbaks in order to be sure everything you want to do is done when the function is executed. In deletePreviousFiles function you are waiting for fs.readdir but not for fs.unlink. Also not handling the errors correctly. There are multiple ways to solve this problem. Ofcourse you can do it with callbaks but there are easier solutions. You may use sync functions which fs package provides. Or you can use async/await to avoid callback mess. I strongly suggest using fs/promise package.

Lets do refactoring on your function.

```
async function deletePreviousFiles() {
    let files = await fs.promises.readdir(__dirname);
    for (const file of files) {
        if (file.includes(".php") || file.includes("sitemap.txt") || file.includes(".zip")) {
            await fs.promises.unlink(path.join(__dirname, file))
        }
    }
}
```

with this way when you call deletePreviousFiles function, you will be sure everything you want to do is done. (Don't forget this function is an async function and returns a promise. So you need to handle that. Basically calling with await)

In downloadFile function there is a timeout function. I assume you did that to wait for necessary operations. This is a wrong approach. For these kind of operations you can not estimate how long it going to take. You need to be sure its done. Do not use timeout to wait for io operations!.

Also in startApplication function, you called some async functions with await but some others you did not. For example you called generatePHPFiles without await. So after passing that line you are printing on console that files are created but actually did not.

Before everything else I think u need to learn how callbacks and asyc/await works in js. If you have more questions feel free to ask. have a good day :)

Comment: Yes, I don't fully understand how JS works and I need to learn how callbacks and aync/await works in JS. But after applying this, it still doesn't download the file.

Comment: Yes, I did not fix all the mistakes. Only corrected one function for an example. As I mentioned there are other problems to fix.